# How do I enter Dano-Norwegian letters like "Æ" in the Computer Modern font in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, special-characters

I could use some help regarding the Computer Modern font in Microsoft Word. I would like to type [Dano-Norwegian letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet) such as æ ø å, but the CM fonts I have found (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf) cannot do that. They change ø å æ to the Arial font instead. Anyone have a suggestion for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Those fonts dated 1995 probably don't contain UTF and/or other extended characters.

Use a different font; one that contains all the characters you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you want to use Computer Modern with Word? It’s like trying to play a VHS tape with a Betamax player.

That being said: These characters are on non-standard positions, due to the fact that these fonts were not to be intended to be used like that, predating Unicode and so on. You can find them with a reasonable font viewer, character map or similar. To take your examples:

- *Æ* is on the code position of *À* in `cmr`.
- *ø* is on the code position of *¿* in `cmr`.
- *æ* is on the code position of *½* in `cmr`.
- *å* you have to build somehow by employing *a* and *º* from `cmr`.

I think there are fonts for this typeface with more reasonable Unicode support though.

Comment: It is because I don't know how to use Latex, but the font in Latex is very neat to look at